# drawViewHierarchyInRect, blinking when presenting SLComposeViewController

Tags: uikit

So, let's say I want to make screenshot and post it on Twitter. SLComposeViewController is blinking when presenting.

```
UIImage *image;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

SLComposeViewController *compose = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[compose addImage:image];
[self presentViewController:compose animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The behavior occurs only when "afterScreenUpdates:YES", "afterScreenUpdates:NO" makes no blinking.

Why does it blink? I test it on iPhone 5.

Comment: same things happens to me..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but here is what worked for me:

Set afterScreenUpdates:NO